# Error in com.sun.speech.freetts.*

Tags: java, text-to-speech, freetts

this is my code

```
import com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager;   


public class FreeTTS {

 private static final String VOICENAME_kevin = "kevin";
 private String text; // string to speech

 public FreeTTS(String text) {
  this.text = text;
 }

 public void speak() {
  Voice voice;
  VoiceManager voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
  voice = voiceManager.getVoice(VOICENAME_kevin);
  voice.allocate();
  voice.speak(text);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String text = "FreeTTS was written by the Sun Microsystems Laboratories "
    + "Speech Team and is based on CMU's Flite engine.";
  FreeTTS freeTTS = new FreeTTS(text);
  freeTTS.speak();
 }
}
```

it is givivng an error on "com.sun.speech" in imports,although i include lib folder from freetts into this project.
Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: dint get it.................

Comment: which tool you are using netbeans or eclipse?

Comment: read my comment for eclipse

Comment: if my answer is helpful you can select my answer

Answer (score 0):

I gone through your code it require **freetts-1.0.jar**
 just download it and then 
add this jar to your project classpath
or create a newfolder in name it **lib** and then paste **freetts-1.0.jar** in that folder( i.e lib) and then add that jar.

Comment: are  you using  netbeans?

Comment: in eclipses go to your project file you will find option "library" there right click on that then click on  "add JAR " then browse to it and find your project folder open that and then click on lib folder open that and you will find your jar file click on that file and click open and problem is solved

Comment: what is that word "library" in your above comment. i couldnt find that.

Comment: in "eclipse" right click on your "project name" than select "built path" and select "add external Archives" than browse and find find your jar